# @font-face with a .css file used as the source?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, cloud.typography

I've been given the path (which I have shortened) to a Gotham font...

```
https://cloud.typography.com/[path shortened]/css/fonts.css
```

Can I use it in a @font-face definition (doesn't seem to work - examples don't use .css as a valid src)?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url("https://cloud.typography.com/[path shortened]/css/fonts.css");
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

so that I can use it like:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; 
}
```

I'm obviously missing something as it's always using the sans-serif fallback, not the required font.

NB The font is paid for and is being tested on the domain that has been correctly licensed by typography for the font)

Comment: I think your url is also a css and it contain the font-face rules, so use import instead of font-face. I mean, inside your css use @import url("https://cloud.typography.com/[path shortened]/css/fonts.css"); and then alle the other rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this on your main css code and call the font name in the font.css as your font-face. this should work

@import url('https://cloud.typography.com/[path shortened]/css/fonts.css');